# MySQL Simple Join Avoid multiple duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say that i have 2 tables:
1st has following columns:

```
products
--------
id   name        price
1  someproduct  99
```

2nd

```
productimages
-----------
productId img
1          someimgurl
1          someimgurl2
```

I would like to get name,price and images of product 1.

```
SELECT products.name, products.price, productimages.img  FROM products INNER JOIN productimages WHERE products.id=1
```

This query gives me following result:

```
[ {
    name: 'someproduct',
    price: 99,
    img:
     'someimg' },
   {
    name: 'someproduct',
    price: 99,
    img:
     'someimgurl2' }
]
```

As you see name and price are repeated.What i am trying to get as result is this:

```
[ {
    name: 'someproduct',
    price: 99,
    img:[
     'someimgurl','someimgurl2'] },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *aggregation* to get a single row.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT p.name, p.price, GROUP_CONCAT(pi.img) as img
FROM products p INNER JOIN
     productimages pi
     on p.id = pi.product_id
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.name, p.price;
```

I also notice that you had a `JOIN` with no `ON` clause.  This would be a syntax error in any database other than MySQL.

Comment: this concats 2 images into one and seperates with ,  is it possible to make each image  element of img array  ? so that img[0] = someimgurl and img[1]  = someimgurl2  or am i wrong  ?

Comment: @lastpeony4 that is not possible, mysql returns complete rows of fields, and fields can only hold single values.

Comment: so what is the proper way to achieve this ? am i gonna seperate them on server side before sending data back to client ?

Comment: @lastpeony4 . . . There is no such thing as an array in MySQL.  You need to parse the resulting string into an array at the application level.